# Need Help Regarding SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Many track is named with the word ‘love’ in the database.For which i need ti Write a single SQL statement to list all the songs in  the Track table with a name that both begins and ends with the word ‘love’.

Kindly Help me there, i didn't get how to  start  and  how to  end.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a site for homework.  Please show some effort has been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your WHERE clause using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT songname FROM trackTable WHERE songname LIKE 'love%' OR songname LIKE '%love'
```

Here `%` is the wildcard, so we look for where there is anything (using the wildcard) and then the word `love` OR where there is the word `love` and then anything (again using the wildcard).

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of LIKE? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

```
Where songName like 'love%' or songName like '%love'
```

Answer (score 0):

-- IF you need your song start and end both with love then use this one

```
SELECT songname FROM trackTable WHERE songname LIKE 'love%love'
```

-- IF you need your song start with love or end with love then use this one

```
SELECT songname FROM trackTable WHERE songname LIKE 'love%' or  songname LIKE '%love'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Track 
WHERE songName LIKE 'love%' OR City LIKE '%love';
[quick example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like)